# Do I have to uninstall NVIDIA drivers before replacing with an AMD GPU?

Tags: ati, graphics, intel, ram, pcie

Here is the setup:

- Old Intel motherboard (DG33FB) with PCI-X 1.0
- 2 GB DDR2 system memory
- 580 W PSU
- Intel Core 2 Quad 2.4 GHz

Here are the observations*:

- I had thought there was no POST or BIOS but if I press F2 even without seeing, BIOS does show up. *POST and BIOS screens are invisible.*
- System hangs after BIOS with code on the bottom left "0_".
- The GPU and PSU are fine based on my visit to the store I bought the GPU at.

I don't want to recklessly spend more money for desperate fixes.

Is is possible that it isn't booting because it's having conflict with the GPU drivers?

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have multiple ram sticks?  If so try pulling one and booting.  Then switch. Also try w no video and listen for post tone.

Comment: No. It's just the one 2 GB. The system boots fine with a different GPU (GT 220) but with the same RAM config so I think it will do fine even with integrated graphics.

Comment: It's done. I've avoided it completely. I had them replace the motherboard with one that worked. I don't know what had been the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ive seen ram do wierder things.  In this case you are prob looking at the video card as the culprit.  Possibly the controller.  I recently had to add a usb pci card to my machine because the onboard hub has failed.

Comment: If it were the RAM would my old GPU setup not work either? I updated my observations: the GPU is actually working fine.